# How can I import module python from my local gitlab?

Tags: python, import, module

I used github.com/operatorequals/httpimport, but I get an error: "KeyError: 'test_wr'".
File test_wr.py is located in my gitlab (myserver.locals)

```
import httpimport

url = "http://myserver.locals/admin_user/python_prod/test_all_py/raw/master/test_dir/test_wr.py"
httpimport.INSECURE = True
with httpimport.remote_repo(["test_wr"], url):
    import test_wr
test_wr.init_def('Hi')
```

This code is from test_wr.py:

```
def init_def(*args):
    return args[0]
```

/admin_user/ - Group

/python_prod/ - Group (or subgroup)

/test_all_py/ - Project

/test_dir/ - the directory where the script is located (also is located **init**.py)

Please help me in solve problem!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! Raw url must be: `"http://myserver.locals/admin_user/python_prod/test_all_py/raw/8e904cebf45e7025f68927d8aacd9cb669859002/test_dir"`